# How to recover deleted site in Wordpress Multisite?

Tags: multisite, customization

I went to Network Admin > Sites > clicked on a site and changed the site url for a child site. Now that site is gone altogether and I cannot get it back. What can I do now?

Answer (score 1):

http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.3.1/wp-admin/includes/ms.php#L46

Notice, how `drop` defaults to `false`; this means that the blog tables are not removed. Deleting is triggered from over here: http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.3.1/wp-admin/ms-delete-site.php#L19 and nowhere else by default. Unless you have a plugin that forces drops on the tables there's still a chance to recover something.

First of all [backup the database](http://codex.wordpress.org/Backing_Up_Your_Database) before attempting anything.

To get the blog to be displayed in the list you have to reverse the following action:

```
update_blog_status( $blog_id, 'deleted', 1 );
```

You can do this manually via MySQL:

```
UPDATE `wp_blogs` SET `deleted` = 0 WHERE `blog_id` = '##'
```

Or `update_blog_status( ##, 'deleted', 0 );` in your *functions.php* once.

The users will, unfortunately be gone, due to this in a loop:

```
remove_user_from_blog( $user_id, $blog_id );
```

...performing even if the tables aren't dropped.

The rest - settings, files, etc. should be all intact.

Good luck.

Comment: The SQL did not work. In table wp-blogs there is nothing with deleted=1. I did find all the page content in the table wp_4_posts.

Comment: If you see and understand that the tables for the blog are empty or non-existent - then, unfortunately, without some sort of backup everything is lost.